# Generating a complete graph in metric space

Tags: graph, networkx

Please help with the simplest  way to generate a complete random weighted undirected graph given size N, so that weights form a metric space (obey triangle inequality). I know there is networkx library but not sure how to do this.

Comment: Without any further specification of the random distribution of the edge weights, this problem is simple – just select a random weight between 2 and 3 for each edge.  The resulting graph will trivially satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Paul Sure it would.  The inequality is d(x, y) + d(y, z) >= d(x, z).  The left-hand side is always between 4 and 6, while the right-hand side is between 2 and 3.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I bow to thee. (For those wondering, I was questioning Sven's insight without any argument to back it up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @SvenMarnach is correct, I thought I would mention that it is pretty easy to initialize a graph from a distance matrix in networkx:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

V = 100 # number of nodes
D = 2 # dimensionality

positions = np.random.rand(V, D)
differences = positions[:, None, :] - positions[None, :, :]
distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(differences**2, axis=-1)) # euclidean

# create a weighted, directed graph in networkx
graph = nx.from_numpy_matrix(distances, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Comment: You can randomly embed the graph into an arbitrary metric space.  This example uses the Euclidean plane.  Again, the question we need to answer is whether there are any requirements for the random distribution of the weights.

Comment: @Paul I've managed to understand/visualize finally how you transform random coordinates into distance matrix but it's still difficult for me. Could you recommend any good reading on this?

Comment: Presumably, it's the line `differences = positions[:, None, :] - positions[None, :, :]` that is giving you troubles? What I am doing is called "broadcasting", and very handy feature of numpy arrays. Essentially, it is equivalent to tiling the array in the dimension indicated by `None` (without ever actually creating the tiled array). Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) or google for a decent tutorial.

Comment: @VladimirLenin You can also use [`scipy.spatial.distance_matrix()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html).  If you use Paul's broadcasting approach, I recommend using `np.newaxis` instead of `None`.  It's just an alias for `None`, but makes the intent much clearer for readers of the code (including yourself in six months' time).